# What's the name of a part of a circle that's formed by an arbitrary intersecting line?

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

The curved line is a part of a circle with a center at the lower right corner.

What would be the name of the shaded region?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a [circular segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).